# Improve accuracy of tesseract ocr in android through preprocessing

Tags: java, android, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

The goal is to make on ocr app using tesseract, I didn't wanted to use tess-two as it works on older version of tesseract. So after a little research i was able to find [this library](https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android) which uses tesseract 4 and is a fork of tess-two. I am able to extract text from the image using this library. But my issue is Sometimes the same image gives 80% text and sometimes it gives 2% result. Here is the image :

[image]

and ocr result

[image: ocr result] , whereas the images having table format doesn't gives any result, only random letters.

I am new to ocr, pre-processing, can anyone help me for how can i improve the accuracy of image? I have read pre processing can be done, would that help and how it can be executed?

Thank you!

Comment: Use google library for ocr processing https://developers.google.com/vision/android/text-overview

Comment: Hi @AjayPandya thanks for your reply, but actually i need to use tesseract only, is there any method for it?

Comment: Don't think so, as per my knowledge there be a such method which can improve accuracy it must be on camera scanning

Comment: @AjayPandya by method i mean, any solution like pre processing the image and then sending to tesseract for ocr, i thought of studying how opencv works and to use it but after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361583/how-to-use-opencvtesseract-for-accurate-text-recognition-in-android?rq=1 i guess that also won't help much, still trying to found out if someone has got a solution for this problem.

Comment: @AjayPandya did you find any way to improve OCR results?